# Dyld Message: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/FileProvider

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, c++builder

I'm developing a multi-device app with C++Builder (RAD Studio 10.2.3).

The Android release works, while the iOS does not.

I build the app for iOS using a Mac (MacOS 10.3.4), with Xcode 9.4.1 (with iOS SDK 11.4), with the option to compile both for 32-bit and 64-bit version.

I'm realeasing it for Ad Hoc deployment. My iPad3,3 (iOS 9.3.5) is connected to my PC via USB and synchronized with iTunes. I install the app by drag&drop from the PC to the device in iTunes.

When I run the app on the iPad, a black screen appears for a moment and then nothing. If I read the .crash file in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\myiPadName (synchronized with iTunes) I see:

```
Incident Identifier: 42CFCEA1-EE7A-4AF3-A7A5-4FA5976B1541
CrashReporter Key:   ad037ec0f72fef57d801caab47534a1552cbae5b
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:             MyApp [370]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04BA1DBE-7049-4FAB-9955-7624B233313C/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          it.mycompany.myapp
Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2018-08-31 11:28:52.52 +0200
Launch Time:         2018-08-31 11:28:51.51 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/FileProvider
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/04BA1DBE-7049-4FAB-9955-7624B233313C/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 390.7

Binary Images:
0x50000 - 0x7a3fff FriulMedica armv7  <cdfdbcde54883701825adc5ea65b0b14> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/04BA1DBE-7049-4FAB-9955-7624B233313C/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x1fe60000 - 0x1fe87fff dyld armv7  <146dc907cdf7350eb7cf92a77291119f> /usr/lib/dyld
```

This is just a simple C++ app. If I try with a simple Delphi app... it works...

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue removing FileProvider framework (that seems to be available from iOS 11) from RAD Studio > Tools > Options > Environment Options > SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Testing a simple multi-device application made with C++ Builder (RAD Studio 10.3.3), targeting iOS 32bit with SDK 13.4 to an iPhone 5 iOS 10.3.4 connected to my MacBook Pro macOS 10.15.4, I reached exactly the same issue that described bluish in his post.
And the solution that he proposed worked also for me: removing FileProvider framework from RAD Studio > Tools > Options > Environment Options > SDK Manager.

Comment: Add tags on your question, please